# Font-awesome hover seems have a delay

Tags: css, delay, transition, font-awesome, coloranimation

I am trying to achieve hover animation with font-awesome fa icon-circle.

Problem is "Facebook circle" animation seems comes with delay. How can i achieve faster light on animation without giving smaller number of animation time with transitions.

### HTML

```
<ul class="social-icons">
  <li>
    <a href="#www.facebook.com/mobge">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-3x socialSpan">
        
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x circleIco">
        </i>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x secondIco">
        </i>
        
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  [...]
</ul>
```

### SCSS

```
.socialSpan, .circleIco, .secondIco{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition:all 0.4s;
}
.social-icons{
    li{
        a{
            color: $sublimeGray;
        }
        a:hover{
            color: $facebookColor;
            margin-top: 20px;

        }
    }
    
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaBxE/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply a CSS transition to two extra elements here, which may slow the transition.

It concerns `socialSpan`'s children so remove the transitions applied to:

```
.socialSpan {
    transition:all 0.4s;
}
```

instead of

```
.socialSpan, .circleIco, .secondIco{
    transition:all 0.4s;
}
```

[Demonstration!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AxCnH/)

Comment: Oh! thank you very much! I am a new starter for css and html. so I didn't suspect from performance!

Comment: @ÖzgürTaşkın You're welcome! If my answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted for future visitors. And edit your question to include your code, in case your link ends broken

Comment: Oh i definitely wanted to vote up to your answer but I cannot because I haven't got enough reputation. Once i reach adequate rep. I will return and vote up all answers that I get help from. Thank you again!

Comment: @ÖzgürTaşkın Up-voting and accepting (the green tick) are different things; accepting doesn't require a specific amount of reputation!